# Understanding the structure of published skos concept schemes

Tags: rdf, linked-data, skos

There's something I don't understand about linked data, especially when it comes to skos concept schemes or the rdf data cube vocabulary.
When I search for how to create and publish a skos cocept scheme I usually find something like this: https://www.jenitennison.com/2009/11/22/creating-linked-data-part-iii-defining-concept-schemes.html.
What I dont understand is if I specify everything about every concept in the scheme in one big file like this and publish it at the base URI, do I then also need to publish the rdf data of each concept at a more specific URI ? If so, do I just repeat the chunk of information of that one concept at that more specific URI ?

So following the linked example, URI http://transport.data.gov.uk/def/vehicle-category/
will contain:

```
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@base <http://transport.data.gov.uk/def/vehicle-category/> .

<> a skos:ConceptScheme ;
  skos:prefLabel "Vehicle Types"@en ;
  skos:hasTopConcept <bicycle> ;
  skos:hasTopConcept <motor-vehicle> .
...
<motor-vehicle> a skos:Concept ;
  skos:prefLabel "Motor Vehicle"@en ;
  skos:topConceptOf <> ;
  skos:narrower <motorbike> ;
  skos:narrower <car> ;
  skos:narrower <bus> ;
  skos:narrower <van> ;
  skos:narrower <HGV> .
...
<HGV> a skos:Concept ;
  skos:prefLabel "Heavy Goods Vehicle"@en ;
  skos:altLabel "HGV"@en ;
  skos:definition "Goods vehicles over 3,500 kgs gross vehicle weight."@en ;
  skos:scopeNote "Includes tractors (without trailers), road rollers, box vans and similar large vans. A two axle motor tractive unit without trailer is also included."@en ;
  skos:broader <motor-vehicle> ;
  skos:narrower <HGVr> ;
  skos:narrower <HGVa> ;
  skos:inScheme <> .
...
```

and if I then dereference http://transport.data.gov.uk/def/vehicle-category/motor-vehicle I'll get something like:

```
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@base <http://transport.data.gov.uk/def/vehicle-category/>.
<motor-vehicle> a skos:Concept ;
  skos:prefLabel "Motor Vehicle"@en ;
  skos:topConceptOf <> ;
  skos:narrower <motorbike> ;
  skos:narrower <car> ;
  skos:narrower <bus> ;
  skos:narrower <van> ;
  skos:narrower <HGV> .
```

This doesn't seem very logical to me, so I assume I'm missing some key piece of knowledge. I tried to find some existing skos concept schemes to see how this is actually done, but I couldn't find anything I could understand.

Comment: Do you author all these RDF representations of URIs manually?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I'm not sure, none of the examples including the one I linked mention that. What does that change ?